# How to suppress the author field in the \footfullcite entry?

Tags: beamer, biblatex, xetex

I am writing a beamer slides, and the blank area is limited, so I only want to keep the title, journal or proceeding field in the bibliography entry when use the `\footfullcite` instruction.

The `biblatex` package is loaded with these options:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,isbn=false,doi=false,sorting=none,url=false,style=ieee]{biblatex}
```

---

here's the minimal working example:

the `main.tex`

```
\documentclass[utf8, xcolor=table]{beamer}  
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,isbn=false,doi=false,sorting=none,url=false,style=ieee]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{citation.bib}    
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    this is the context\footfullcite{Yazdanpanah2014}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

the `citation.bib`

```
@Article{Yazdanpanah2014,
  author   = {F. Yazdanpanah and C. Alvarez-Martinez and D. Jimenez-Gonzalez and Y. Etsion},
  title    = {Hybrid Dataflow/von-Neumann Architectures},
  journal  = {IEEE Transactions on Parallel and Distributed Systems},
  year     = {2014},
  volume   = {25},
  number   = {6},
  pages    = {1489--1509},
  month    = jun,
  issn     = {1045-9219},
  doi      = {10.1109/TPDS.2013.125},
  keywords = {data flow computing, multiprocessing systems, parallel architectures, synchronisation, data synchronization, dataflow computing models, dataflow execution models, general purpose hybrid dataflow-von-Neumann architectures, interblock execution model, intrablock execution, parallel platforms, synergistic hybrid computing model, Computational modeling, Computer architecture, Data models, Instruction sets, Parallel processing, Synchronization, Dataflow architectures, hybrid systems, parallel processors, scheduling and task partitioning, von-Neumann model},
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: @samcarter, here's the minimal example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My personal opinion: removing the author sounds kind of strange, if I had to save space, I would remove the title etc. but keep the author and the year.

I would suggest to modify the `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}` according to your needs:

```
\begin{filecontents}{citation.bib}
@Article{Yazdanpanah2014,
  author   = {F. Yazdanpanah and C. Alvarez-Martinez and D. Jimenez-Gonzalez and Y. Etsion},
  title    = {Hybrid Dataflow/von-Neumann Architectures},
  journal  = {IEEE Transactions on Parallel and Distributed Systems},
  year     = {2014},
  volume   = {25},
  number   = {6},
  pages    = {1489--1509},
  month    = jun,
  issn     = {1045-9219},
  doi      = {10.1109/TPDS.2013.125},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[utf8, xcolor=table]{beamer}  
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,isbn=false,doi=false,sorting=none,url=false,style=ieee]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
%  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
%  \newunit
    \nopunct% NEW
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
%  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
\usebibmacro{journal}% NEW
%  \newunit
%  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
%  \newunit
%  \usebibmacro{pages}%
%  \newunit
%  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
%  \newunit
%  \printfield{note}%
%  \newunit\newblock
%  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
%    {\printfield{issn}}
%    {}%
%  \newunit\newblock
%  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
%  \newunit\newblock
%  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
%  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
%  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
%  \newunit\newblock
%  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\addbibresource{citation.bib}    
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    this is the context\footfullcite{Yazdanpanah2014}.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The viewers are not the same field, so I think keeping the title and journal name in the frame is the best way to tell them the citation's brief info and the its authority

Comment: Is there any other way to modify the entry format for all kind of bibitem? Or I can only to modify them separately ?

Comment: @Patrick With this method the drivers have to be declared separately, as they usually display different informations. If you have one or more types which should use the same driver, you could use `\DeclareBibliographyAlias{⟨alias⟩}{⟨entrytype⟩}`.

Comment: thx, that works well. I have an extra question about the `\footfullcite` in a `block` environment. If there are multiple citation, how to set the footnote counter right? For example, I put two `\footnotemark` in the block and and two corresponding `\footnotetext` outside, but the mark's superscript are not the same with its corresponding text

Comment: @Patrick If you have a new question, please ask a new question.